# Get child record values lightning web component

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components

I am trying to get account child object contact record values by using **getRecordUi**

in **recordIds** i am passing Account Record Id. I am getting a big JSON response. But in that response i am not finding any Contact object related fields. Only thing which i got is below . Am i doing correctly. 
What is the way to get child record detail values.

```
      {
         "childObjectApiName":"Contact",
          "fieldName":"AccountId",
          "junctionIdListNames":[

          ],
          "junctionReferenceTo":[

          ],
          "relationshipName":"Contacts"
       },
```

JS -

```
 @wire(getRecordUi , { recordIds: '0012v00002InPVmAAN', childRelationships: "Account.Contacts", layoutTypes: 'Full', modes: 'View' })
    contactRecord ({ error, data }) {
        if(data) {
            let conts = data;
            for (let key in conts) {
                if (key) {
                  this.mapData.push({ value: conts[key], key: key });
                }
              }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.mapData));
    }
```

Comment: Browsing https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record_ui I didn'f find `childRelationships` request field. Maybe it's not supported.